# How to allow image from gallery or camera option together for input file type

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a page in which the user click on upload image button and get options list in which he can choose image from camera directly or go to gallery. I've done lots of searches on google and here on stackoverflow but none of the found results answers my question. I need your help please. 
It wouldn't be a problem is there is a way of doing it in jquery if not only in the input tag itself.
if I try this the way it is, i get list of options Camera, documents and other but not gallery

here is the file tag i am using for now:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" class="profile_picture_file_input" id="profile_picture_file_upload"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late but for the record:

It's supposed to be a comma `,` not semi-colon `;`

```html
<p>Drop-down and Images only</p>
<input type="file" accept="capture=camera,image/*" />
```

[image]

Why are most articles and tutorials using `;` is beyond me :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same thing not so long ago.  What worked for (my phone at least) it's just remove the "capture" and let android handle it.

It will open the gallery first and give the option to access de camera.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="profile_picture_file_input" id="profile_picture_file_upload" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="profile_picture_file_input" id="profile_picture_file_upload" capture>
```

Comment: This one opens the camera directly and doesn't allow for any other options